# Dynamic classes in Java with minimal memory overhead

Tags: java

In my application I need to create dynamic classes/types/objects. I would usually solve it using `HashMap<K,V>`(thanks to simplicity opposing to reflection), something like:

```
class DynObject {
   private HashMap<String,Object> fields;
}
```

However, I need to create a lot of these objects - I mean really *a lot* (I am running low on memory already ).
I had an idea - there are groups ("types") of instances with same fields and because of that keeping the map on every single instance is redundant. In order to cut down the size of each instance, I tried to move the `HashMap<K,V>` to separate class:

```
class DynamicType {

    private HashMap<String, Integer> fields = new HashMap<>();
    private String name;

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getFields() { return fields; }
}

class Dynamic {
    private Object[] values;
    private DynamicType type;

    public Dynamic(DynamicType ofType)
    {
        type = ofType;
        values = new Object[type.getFields().size()];
    }

    public Object getField(String name) { 
       return values[type.getFields().get(name)]; 
    }
    public void setField(String name, Object value) { 
       values[type.getFields().get(name)] = value; 
    }
}
```

...which would work perfectly, but there is another problem - I need to add need fields on a type from time to time and with this scenario the changes(adding only) to `DynamicType`s fields would not reflect retrospectively to its `Dynamic` instances.
I do not know in advance how many classes there are, their names or their fields, moreover need for extra field for existing classes can be "discovered" at any point. The overall actual stored data size is enormous.
tl;dr: How do I create a dynamic types with fields String->Object to keep the memory overhead minimal on their instances?

---

I ended up using conjunction of the accepted answer and the idea using lazy values allocation implementing own `LazyList<T>`, testing shows it saves up to 50% of memory (tested using 5 fields of various types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most memory effective way to do this, would be by:

1. Switching arrays to Lists.
2. Maintaining backreferences from DynamicType to each of it's instances.

This way, DynamicType could be able to scale each of it's instances whenever needed. It would look something like this:

```
class DynamicType {
    private final String name;

    private Map<String, Integer> fields = new HashMap<>();
    private List<Dynamic> instances = new ArrayList<>();

    public DynamicType(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Dynamic createInstance() {
        Dynamic d = new Dynamic(this);

        for (int i=0;i<fields.size();i++) {
            d.addField(null); //Some default value for uninitialized fields
        }

        instances.add(d);
        return d;
    }

    public void addField(String name, Object defaultValue) {
        fields.put(name, fields.size());

        for (Dynamic d : instances) {
            d.addField(defaultValue);
        }
    }

    protected Integer getFieldIdx(String name) {
        return fields.get(name);
    }
}

class Dynamic {
    private List<Object> values;
    private DynamicType type;

    protected Dynamic(DynamicType ofType)
    {
        type = ofType;
        values = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    protected void addField(Object value) {
        values.add(value);
    }

    public Object getField(String name) { 
       return values.get(type.getFieldIdx(name)); 
    }

    public void setField(String name, Object value) { 
       return values.set(type.getFieldIdx(name), value); 
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
DynamicType t = new DynamicType("t");
t.addField("name", null);
t.addField("age", null);

Dynamic t1 = t.createInstance();
Dynamic t2 = t.createInstance();

t.addField("sex", "male"); //Now both t1 and t2 have sex -> male
```

P.S. Code is not tested, but should work in theory.

**Old answer:**

If I understood your problem correctly, you have duplication of `String` keys, as most of the fields have same names on your "dynamic objects".

Therefore, the best solution is to just make a separate index of those Strings, so that all HashMaps share the same instance. You would get additional overhead on write operations, but save a lot of memory in case the keys are the problem.

Something like this (no OOP, but the idea should be obvious):

```
Map<String, String> fieldNameIndex = new HashMap<>();

void addEntry(Map<String, Object> map, String name, Object value) {
    String existingName = fieldNameIndex.get(name);
    if (existingName == null) {
        fieldNameIndex.put(name, name);
        existingName = name;
    }

    map.put(existingName, value);
}
```

Basically, this code maintains an internal index of all used keys, and allocates new ones if no existing key is found in the index. Therefore, if you create N objects with the same key, they will all reference the same String instance.

Also, depending on how often the new objects are appearing and how fast should this operation perform - you may want to switch the index to a TreeMap. HashMaps will perform better if new field names are constantly being added. However, if after the initial load new keys are added rarely - TreeMap would probably perform better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think  this was misunderstanding - see the second code listing. I needed to create a dynamic class/type, that can be be expanded with more field its over lifetime (keeping its instances valid). In the first half of the question I try to explain why I just dont create a hash map for each object instance which would work but produce enormous memory overhead - a hash map with 20 String keys  is a lot of memory compared to actual stored data in an instance. e.g. I have 100 000 instances ClassA, 76300 of ClassB for which I need to add fields and more ClassX dynamically.

Comment: I do not know in advance how many classes there are, their names or their fields, moreover need for extra field for existing classes can be "discovered" any time.

Comment: @wondra Either there's still misunderstanding, or that's exactly what I explained in my answer. Currently you are trying to use array index to locate the field name. If your "DynamicType" tells you that the field has index of "15" - that's what you are looking for in your `Object[]` array. However, this will not work for scaling in any way. I'll add a bit more explanation to my answer on how it helps you with your problem.

Comment: I see it now, sharing string instances instead of map instances - clever. I will try this solution and report back/accept.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking it through, it will probably not help you at all. The overhead from having maps in each of your Dynamic objects is still pretty huge. Even though the key itself will be cached, the buckets in the map will not.

Comment: Updated my answer with a different approach, will add a code example soon.

Comment: I also just had an idea with lazily allocated `Object[]` extending size with `null`s if higher than length index is accessed, I am not sure how to implement this, what underlying type use (my knowledge of Java standard library is weak - not a language I usually use).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116891/discussion-between-wondra-and-bezmax).

Comment: There is no need to do things like this. A `HashMap` is actually a mapping between ints and objects. If you have a `HashMap` where the keys are strings, no strings are actually stored, but only a hash is stored, hence the name.

Comment: @vidstige You are wrong. Hash is not enough to uniquely identify the item. In HashMap hashes are only used to create buckets for objects. After the corresponding bucket is found, it can contain several different keys with the same hash. That's why a proper key is then found in the bucket using `equals` check on the key. Just think about it, hash is an integer, what if I have more objects than integers? How is hash calculated for `HashMap<Long, Object>` for example ?